# Can't insert into database using data manipulation API-Moodle

Tags: php, database, moodle

I'm trying to insert data from a form into the database when a user clicks on the save button but i'm getting these error messages:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\moodleFile\server\moodle\local\try\process.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: university_id in C:\moodleFile\server\moodle\local\try\process.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function insert_record() on a non-object in C:\moodleFile\server\moodle\local\try\process.php on line 15

These are the codes of the file which is called when the user clicks on the Save button:

```
<?php

global $DB;

$name = $_POST['name'];
$uni_id = $_POST['university_id'];

$record1 = new stdClass();
$record1->name  = $name;
$record1->displayorder = '10000';
$record2 = new stdClass();
$record2->name = $uni_id;
$record2->displayorder = '10000';
$records = array($record1, $record2);
$lastinsertid = $DB->insert_record('tbl_faculty', $records);

if(!$lastinsertid)
{
    echo "Could not insert";
}

?>
```

I'm new to Moodle can someone help me out please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Include config.php at the top of any user facing code.
require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/config.php');

// Never trust input from the web, always use optional_param() or required_param() and specify the value type.
$name = optional_param('name', null, PARAM_TEXT);
$uni_id = optional_param('university_id', null, PARAM_TEXT);

$record1 = new stdClass();
$record1->name  = $name;
$record1->displayorder = '10000';

$record2 = new stdClass();
$record2->name = $uni_id;
$record2->displayorder = '10000';

// Insert one record at a time.
$lastinsertid1 = $DB->insert_record('faculty', $record1);
$lastinsertid2 = $DB->insert_record('faculty', $record2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much but i'm still getting this error:Fatal error: Call to a member function insert_record() on a non-object in C:\MoodleWindowsInstaller-latest\moodleFile\server\moodle\local\try\process.php on line 16

Comment: Ah yes, probably because config.php needs to be included first - I've updated the answer.